# How to fill a triangle with gradient using three colors? (maybe using GD)

Tags: ruby, geometry, gd, gradient

What is the best way to fill a triangle with gradient, which is formed using three triange vertices. (for example, {RED, BLUE, GREEN})
Implementation language is ruby. Maybe there're some gems or you know such implementation in GD or GD2 library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RMagick. It's a ruby interface for imagemagick

Try using the [sparse_color function](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image3.html#sparse_color)

Comment: It's filling all image with specified color centroids... I need just to fill a triangle. Using rmagick I will have to do some unnecessary operations like cropping, inserting...